# FFmpeg: Not able to decode H264 encoded file using Ffmpeg library functions

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, codec

> I am trying to decode a H264 encoded attached file using FFmpeg
>   library functions...

```
avformat_open_input() 
av_read_frame() 
avcodec_send_packet() 
avcodec_recieve_frame() .
```

File:- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t_0nh-6jm5d3VpWIRVd25wYKNvt4Yjo7
When i decode it using-

> ffplay frame1.bin

command it gives me the output image.
But when i am trying to decode it using the C program it gives error on `avcodec_recieve_frame()`. It returns -11.

Part of my code i am using for decoding purpose..

```
uint8_t *inbuf = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*(INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE));
  uint8_t *data;

              size_t   data_size;
              int ret=0;

              /* set end of buffer to 0 (this ensures that no overreading happens for damaged MPEG streams) */
              memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);


       pkt = av_packet_alloc();

       if (!pkt)
              exit(1);

       /* find the video decoder */

       codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
       if (!codec) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
              exit(1);
       }

       parser = av_parser_init(codec->id);
       if (!parser) {
              fprintf(stderr, "parser not found\n");
              exit(1);
       }

       c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
       if (!c) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
              exit(1);
       }

       /* open it */
       if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
              exit(1);
       }      
      char *filename = "D:\\frame1.bin";
       fopen_s(&f, filename, "rb");
       printf("\n%s", filename);
       if (!f) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
              exit(1);
       }


       frame = av_frame_alloc();
       frameRGB = av_frame_alloc();
       if (!frame || !frameRGB) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
              exit(1);
       }                   
       while (!feof(f)) {
                         //Reading complete data in one go.. INBUF_SIZE=FILE_SIZE 
                           data_size = fread(inbuf, 1, INBUF_SIZE, f);

                            if (!data_size)
                                  break;

                           /* use the parser to split the data into frames */
                           data = inbuf;
                           while (data_size > 0) {

                                  ret = av_parser_parse2(parser, c, &pkt->data, &pkt->size,
                                         data, data_size, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0);
                                  if (ret < 0) {
                                         fprintf(stderr, "Error while parsing\n");
                                         goto even;
                                  }



                                                data += ret;
                                                data_size -= ret;


                                  if (pkt->size)
                                  {

                                         AVCodecContext *dec_ctx = c;
                                         char buf[1024];
                                         int ret_send_pkt, ret_recv_frame;
                                         struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;


                                         ret_send_pkt = avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, pkt);
                                         if (ret_send_pkt < 0) {
                                                fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a packet for decoding\n");
                                                //exit(1);
                                                goto even;
                                         }

                                         while (ret_send_pkt >= 0) {
                                                ret_recv_frame = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
                                                if (ret_recv_frame == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret_recv_frame == AVERROR_EOF)
                                                {
                                                       //fprintf(stderr, "Error during decoding11\n");
                                                       goto even;                                                   
                                                }
                                                else if (ret_recv_frame < 0) {
                                                       fprintf(stderr, "Error during decoding\n");
                                                       //exit(1);
                                                       goto even;
                                                }


                                         }
                                  even:  ;
                                  }

                           }

                     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-11 is EAGAIN. It means it needs more data to decode the frame. Keep sending packets until a frame is returned. Then flush at the end by sending a null packet.

Comment: thanx for the reply, I tried appending the 2nd frame data and now it's able to decode the frames. But i was wondering why ffplay can decode the frame with the above file only and the C library function need more data to decode the frame.... i am new to ffmpeg can you please explain what is missing in file for proper decoding,,........... Actually what i am trying to do is recieve packet one by one and decode it.. custome multiplexes stream is coming i have to parse a frame manually and decode it... that;s y i was trying to decode frame one by one ..

Comment: Ffplay sends frames to the decoder as fast as it can. It is performing the exact logic I described. Your err is assuming ffplay is processing one frame in, one frame out. It is not.

Comment: Ok but this file contains only frame data and nothing more... still ffplay is able to decode and why C functions need more data? does ffplay itself includes extra data or what? is there some resources available which i can go through to understand it better.. thanx

Comment: The best resource is the ffplay source code. Or the ffmpeg decode example source. Ffplay uses the exact same C functions. It just uses them correctly and sends the next frame as it’s available.

Comment: When in my answer I say “more data” I meant “more frames”. So having “only frame data” is fine.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but ,,, this file contains exactly one frame .. which ffplay is able to decode but the code i have given above is not...

Comment: As I said in the answer, when you run out of frames, you must call send with a empty packet to flush any latent frames in the pipeline. Then call recv until it’s is complete.

Comment: Thanx @szatmary... i got it right now .. during editing i had missed it ... now by calling decoder once more and the end i got the frame... thank you..